# Oracle DELETE busting TEMP space

Tags: oracle, sql-delete, oracle12c, sqlperformance

I have a table with 17 billion rows. I want to delete some of those, present in another table.

I tried a delete statement, parallelized, that did not complete because the temp space wasn't enough.

```
delete /* + PARALLEL(a, 32) */
  from a
 where (a.key1, a.key2) in
         (select /*+ PARALLEL(b, 16) */
                 key1,
                 key2
            from b);
```

Then I tried create table as select that also failed because of the same reason.

```
create table a_temp parallel 32 nologging as
       select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
              key1,
              key2,
              rest_of_data
         from a
        where (a.key1, a.key2) not in
                (select key1, key2 from b);
```

A regular (without PARALLEL) delete was taking more than one day so I had to terminate it.

Is there a way to free temp space as it is not needed anymore, during delete execution?

Is there another way I could do this?

EDIT:
B has 173 million records, and almost 16 billion records have to be deleted (almost the whole table). There are no indexes on the table.

EDIT2:
The explain plan for the create table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS         6749420 177523935   10828960035
 PX COORDINATOR                 
  PX SEND QC (RANDOM)   SYS :TQ10001    6740915 177523935   10828960035
   LOAD AS SELECT (HYBRID TSM/HWMB) USER    A_TEMP          
    OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING          6740915 177523935   10828960035
     MERGE JOIN ANTI NA         6740915 177523935   10828960035
      SORT JOIN         6700114 17752393472 745600525824
       PX BLOCK ITERATOR            45592   17752393472 745600525824
        TABLE ACCESS FULL   USER    A   45592   17752393472 745600525824
      SORT UNIQUE           40802   173584361   3298102859
       PX RECEIVE           5365    173584361   3298102859
        PX SEND BROADCAST   SYS :TQ10000    5365    173584361   3298102859
         PX BLOCK ITERATOR          5365    173584361   3298102859
          TABLE ACCESS FULL USER    B   5365    173584361   3298102859
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many rows are you planning on deleting?  How many rows are in b?  Is there an index on `key1, key2`?  What is the query plan?  I would expect the optimizer to consider rewriting this query as an `exists` but you could possibly try doing that yourself.

Comment: Can you post the explain plan for the `CREATE TABLE`?  Run `explain plan for create table ...` and then run `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` and post the whole results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, using a different solution.

I created manually the `a_temp` table and did an `insert` with an `APPEND PARALLEL` hint. The temp space wasn't exceeded and the inserts performed perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
create table a_temp(..);

insert /* + APPEND PARALLEL(a_temp, 32) */
  into a_temp(...)
select /* + PARALLEL(a, 32) */
       (...)
  from a
 where not exists
       (select /* + PARALLEL(b, 16) */
               '1'
          from b
         where a.key1 = b.key1
           and a.key2 = b.key2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue in the past, I have deleted in batches of ~1M at a time.  After a lot of digging for a cleaner solution, a DBA insisted that I take this approach.

**This was my workflow:**

I used Python and the `cx_Oracle` module to read in the PK values for the to-be-deleted records, iteratively plugged them into an `executemany` call as bind variables, and committed after every iteration.

**If you want to stick with a Parallel Execution Approach:**
Remember to use `ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML` so that your merge or delete is executed in parallel too.  Check out this great blog post that walks you through this:
https://dioncho.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/interpreting-parallel-merge-statement/

Comment: Hello Deano, I considered doing batch deletes in PL/SQL, but usually SQL is faster thank PL/SQL, and the update statement without parallel was taking more than a day. Would using python speed things up? I guess the database work is still there, just with more overhead, no? Thanks!

Comment: Python won't inherently speed things up.  The benefit here is that it allows you run run straight SQL against the database on specified batch sizes.  Python will just pass in parameters and submit your SQL to Oracle.  I imagine you could use this type of strategy with a variety of tools.

Comment: Edited to include tips on parallel execution